# API for local control of Spotify

Tags: python-3.x, spotify

Are there any API's that allow control of the local Spotify program without the need of authentication?

I have found ones like Spotify-local and Spotify-local-connect but it seems these are now outdated and do not work. I just want the program I am developing to be plug and play, not to have to rewrite the program for every Spotify account it uses, which seems to be the case with the Web API.

Comment: To be fair, authentication is pretty effortless with the Web API. Give permissions and login once, use the access tokens practically forever. You simply need to save the refresh tokens. I would recommend trying out some Web API wrapper, like [this](https://pypi.org/project/tekore/). Disclaimer though, I am the author of said wrapper and there are also others available. But I agree, having a local solution could benefit some applications a lot. Have you found one since asking this question?

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't find anything short of having it open Spotify and physically click the pause button which is way too much effort so I just used the standard authentication process for each user instead. Thanks for the help though!